# Tuple comparison in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples

I am wondering why my comparison returns `False` and not `True` although `'a' == 'a'`.

```
def test(*values):
    return values[0]=='a'

tuple = ('a',)
test(tuple)
```

Output: `False`

Comment: Put `print(values)` in your function to discover the answer.

Comment: Hint: you're not evaluating `'a' == 'a'`, you're evaluating `('a',) == 'a'`. Check what `values` is inside `test`.

Comment: Because `values[0] == ('a',)`, not `'a'`, why did you expect different? Did you try and `print(values)` to see what was going on?

Comment: `test(*tuple)` would work because it unpacks the values in `tuple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using `*values` rather than `values` in your function definition

When you use the special syntax `*args` in a function, `args` will already come back as a tuple, where each arg is an element of the tuple.

So for example

```
> def print_args(*args):
    print(args)
> print_args('a', 'b', 'c')

# Outputs:
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

In your case since you are passing in a tuple already, w/in the function `values` is like "Ok, I'll happily take a tuple as my first argument", and `values` becomes a tuple of tuples (well a tuple of a single tuple).  Thus you are comparing ('a',) to 'a' and your check fails

TL;DR: either pass in just `'a'` or change `*values` to `values`

```
def test(values):
    return values[0] == 'a'

tuple = ('a',)
test(tuple)

# Outputs:
True
```

Comment: Another option would be to call `test(*tuple)`, if you are expecting the items in `tuple` to be passed as individual arguments to `test`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the *args syntax in the function declaration means that all parameters will be collected into a new tuple. When you pass your tuple now to this function, it will create a tuple with only one element since you passed only one argument. The value of `values` is `(('a',),)` a tuple with tuple in it. What you probably meant to do was to spread the tuple into the function call which involves the same asterisk syntax: `test(*tuple)` which results in `values == ('a',)` as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function like this:

```
def f(*v):
    print(v)
    return v[0] == 'a'
```

then call f(('a',)), you'll get
(('a',),)
False
function gets a tuple ('a',) not 'a'

Answer (score 0):

quote

def func(*args, **kwargs): ...
var-keyword: specifies that arbitrarily many keyword arguments can be provided (in addition to any keyword arguments already accepted by other parameters). Such a parameter can be defined by prepending the parameter name with **, for example kwargs in the example above.

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter

your not passing a pointer to the type using *args.  the parser thinks your passing keyword arguments